# Python adding to the list

Tags: python, list, split

I have to strip whitespace for extracted strings, one string at a time for which I'm using split(). The split() function returns list after removing white spaces. I want to store this in my own dynamic list since I have to aggregate all of the strings.

The snippet of my code:

```
 while rec_id = "ffff"
        output = procs.run_cmd("get sensor info", command)
        sdr_li = []
        if output:
           byte_str = output[0]
           str_1 = byte_str.split(' ')
           for byte in str_1:
               sdr_li.append(byte)
         rec_id = get_rec_id()

Output = ['23 0a 06 01 52 2D 12']
str_1 = ['23','0a','06','01','52','2D','12']
```

This does not look very elegant, transferring from one list to another. Is there another way to achieve this.

Comment: `sdr_li = [byte for byte in str.split(' ')]`

Comment: wtf is `byte_str` used for, and where did `str` come from? also fix your indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.extend()`:

```
sdr_li.extend(str_1)
```

Comment: Note that if you use this approach, you still need to pull the definition of sdr_li out of the loop, since you'll be clobbering it.

Answer (score 0):

str.split() returns you a list so just add your list's items to the main list. Use `extend` https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

so rewriting your data into something legible and properly indented you'd get:

```
my_list = list
while rec_id = "ffff"
    output = procs.run_cmd("get sensor info", command)
    if output:
        result_string = output[0]
        # extend my_list with the list resulting from the whitespace
        # seperated tokens of the output
        my_list.extend( result_string.split() )
        pass # end if
    rec_id = get_rec_id()
    ...
    pass # end while
```